# IN-App Purchase Pop-up Text

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6, in-app-purchase

I am facing a strange issue. When a user presses a button for cancel in in-app purchase pop-up hides at that time but the pop-up comes twice when he presses the cancel button again. This is getting replicated 100%.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably somewhere in the line of implementing

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

after calling SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.  If you are expecting more assistance, perhaps, you should show your code in the first place.